# How to refer to "mainland Europe"

Tags: word-choice, terminology, geography

As a Europhile living in England, it really bothers me when journalists refer to mainland Europe as "Europe". We're *in* Europe! But I appreciate that it offers a neat shorthand for referring to the continent.

Is there an alternative that doesn't offend my inclusive sensibilities?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**The Continent**

> In the United Kingdom, the Continent
>   is used to refer to the mainland of
>   Europe.

(..)

> A famous, perhaps apocryphal, British
>   newspaper headline once read "Fog in
>   Channel; Continent Cut Off".

(..)

> Derivatively, the adjective
>   "Continental" refers to the social
>   practices or fashion of continental
>   Europe, as opposed to those in
>   Britain. Examples include breakfast
>   and, historically, long-range driving
>   before Britain had motorways.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continental_Europe

Comment: Does 'the Continent' include Norway, Sweden, and Finland? Although the parts of the former Soviet Union that join Finland to Poland are geographically considered to be part of Europe, they are often lumped into Asia, along with the rest of the former Soviet Union.

Comment: In this usage, *The Continent*, notwithstanding  the dictionary definitions of *continent*, may include not only the mainland Europe, but also European islands other than the British ones.

Answer (score 5):

**Continental Europe**

> Continental Europe, also referred to
>   as mainland Europe or simply the
>   Continent, is the continent of Europe,
>   explicitly excluding European
>   islands. **Notably, in British
>   English usage, the term means Europe
>   excluding the United Kingdom, the Isle
>   of Man, the Channel Islands, Ireland
>   and Iceland.**

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continental_Europe

For example, here in England you may have heard "continental breakfast" as a reference to the kind of breakfast that is common in most countries in Continental Europe: croissants, butter, coffee, etc.

Comment: as a _short_hand for "mainland Europe" this doesn't work, as it's two syllables longer...

Comment: Ok. I just posted a separate answer with the alternative "the continent".